# my firebase dependencies cannot be updated

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies

I'm having a bit of a problem with my project. my firebase dependencies cannot be updated.

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: customimageclassifier
description: Crowdsource data for ML models


version: 1.0.4

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13
  camera: 0.5.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  http: ^0.12.2
  timeago: ^2.0.30
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  intro_slider: ^2.3.4
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  automl_mlkit:
    path: ../automl_mlkit/
  firebase_auth:
    path: ../firebase_auth/
  firebase_storage:
    path: ../firebase_storage/
  firebase_messaging:
    path: ../firebase_messaging/

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/labels.txt
    - assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite
    - images/
```

This is the result I got when I ran pub get

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-app...                     

Because every version of firebase_storage from path depends on firebase_core ^0.3.0 and cloud_firestore >=0.16.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0, firebase_storage from path is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=0.16.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0.
So, because customimageclassifier depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.16.0+1 and firebase_storage from path, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because customimageclassifier depends on both cloud_firestore ^0.16.0+1 and firebase_storage from path, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I got the source code for this project form
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/mlkit-custom-image-classifier

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thats happened because you have some packages depends on firebase_core different versions.

you need to use `dependency_overrides` like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13
  ...

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
```